# Gridview in parent page is not refreshing after closing child page - ASP.NET WEB APP

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a parent page and it contains a gridview and an aspx button. when user clicks on this button a child page will popup as modal. After inserting data from child page it should close and refresh the parent page. As a result gridview on parent page should show the inserted data. But using below code gridview is not refreshing.

Parent.aspx Page:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    string sqlquery=""//query here
    SqlDataAdapter da = null;
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlquery);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    dt.AcceptChanges();
    gv_dept.DataSource = null;
    gv_dept.DataSource = dt;
    gv_dept.DataBind();  
    update_gv.Update();
}
  

<a href="#" id="toolbar_day2" onclick="create();">
                 Add New</a>
 <div align="center">
           <asp:UpdatePanel ID="update_gv" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
      <ContentTemplate>
              <asp:GridView ID="gv_dept" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"   
                GridLines="Both"  DataKeyNames="dept_id">                     
    <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="dept_name" HeaderText="Name" /> 
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
function create(start, end, resource) {
    createModal().showUrl('Child.aspx');
}
function createModal() {
    var modal = new DayPilot.Modal();
    modal.closed = function () {
        if (this.result && this.result.refresh) {
            dp_day.commandCallBack("refresh", { message: this.result.message });
            dp_week.commandCallBack("refresh", { message: this.result.message });
            dp_month.commandCallBack("refresh", { message: this.result.message });
        }
        dp_day.clearSelection();
        dp_week.clearSelection();
        dp_month.clearSelection();
    };

    return modal;
}
DayPilot.Modal = function() {

        // default values
        this.autoStretch = true;  // height will be increased automatically to avoid scrollbar, until this.maxHeight is reached
        this.autoStretchFirstLoadOnly = false;
        this.border = "10px solid #008080";
        this.corners = 'Rounded';
        this.className = null;
        this.dragDrop = true;
        this.height = 650;  // see also autoStretch
        this.maxHeight = null; // if not set, it will stretch until the bottom space is equal to this.top
        this.opacity = 30;
        this.scrollWithPage = true;  // modal window will scroll with the page
        this.top = 3;
        this.useIframe = true; // only for showHtml()
        this.width = 880;
        this.zIndex = null;
   }
```

Child.aspx Page:

```
protected async void ButtonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//Inserting data here.
  Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
            ht["refresh"] = "yes";
            ht["message"] = "Created.";
            Modal.Close(this, ht);
     Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "RefreshParentPage", "<script language='javascript'>RefreshParentPage();</script>");
}
function RefreshParentPage() {
        window.location.href="Parent.aspx";
}
```

When putting breakpoints on gridview binding, the datatable reflects the newly inserted rows. But gridview is not refreshing with it.

Comment: Hum, I don't see the markup, nor the button code that runs when you click that add button, and then how that popup works. It is  assumed that the button ok button when clicked in that popup adds to the table, and then that same code-binds the gv to show the new row. However, I would just move your page load to a routine that both the page load (is postback = false) then can call, and then the same routine can be called after you add the row to the database table. But, yes, as a general rule you have to re-load/re-bind the grid for the new row to show.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Sorry didn't get what you said

Comment: All I am saying is you don't show your button code, and how you poping that dialog - so we can only guess what is going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here how we can do this.
the BIG WHOPPER issue is we don't really know what kind of dialog you are popping.

And I count about what, 150 DIFFERENT dialog utilities we can go and grab?

But, lets use one of the more popular ones. (jQuery.UI). Since we all use jQuery rather often, might as well add the jQuery.UI to your application.

However, ANY KIND of dialog system will work.

So, lets assume we have a Grid, say like this:

```
      <asp:GridView ID="MyGrid" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover" 
          DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >

        <Columns>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"  />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="Hotel Name" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Province" HeaderText="Province" />
           <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active" />

        </Columns>
    
      </asp:GridView>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="cmdAdd" runat="server" Text="Add Hotel" OnClientClick="popadd();return false;"/>
```

And our code behind to load this grid:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            LoadGrid();
        }
    }

    public void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * From tblHotels ORDER by HotelName",
            new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST3)))
        {
            // now load grid
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            MyGrid.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader();
            MyGrid.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Ok, the above, we now have this:

[image]

And note the above plain jane button - add hotels.

We like most dialog systems, now have to add our "add hotel" markup.
A simple div, with some text boxes, and of course a add or cancel button.

So, I have this simple markup:

```
    <div id="mypop" style="display:none">
        <br />
        <div style="text-align:right">
        <p>Hotel Name:<asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>
        <p>First Name:<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>
        <p>Last Name:<asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>
        <p>City:<asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>
        <p>Province:<asp:TextBox ID="txtProvince" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>
        <p>Is Active:<asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox></p>

        <p>
            <asp:Button ID="cmdAddOk" runat="server" Text="Ok-add" OnClick="cmdAddOk_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="cmdCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" Style="margin-left:25px"
                OnClientClick="MyClose();return false"/>

        </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

(note how display = none - the dialog (jQuery.UI) will turn on the display of this dialog for us.

And now our JS code for the pop button.

```
     <script>

            function popadd() {
                var mydiv = $('#mypop')
                mydiv.dialog({
                    autoOpen: false, modal: true, title: 'Add Hotel', width: '400px',
                    position: { my: 'top', at: 'top+150' },
                    closeText: ''
                    
                });
                // Open the dialog
                mydiv.parent().appendTo($("form:first"))
                mydiv.dialog('open')
            }

            function MyClose() {

                var mydiv = $('#mypop')
                mydiv.dialog('close')

            }
        </script>
```

And now we simple write some code to add a row to the data table. There are a gazillion ways to do this, but I often actually use a data row, since it saves me a HUGE WACK OF SQL and parameters - this approach can be a real time saver.

And it feels like MS Access or old FoxPro days - easy code to write!!!

So, in the dialog, we have two buttons. the cancel button just closes the dialog.
but the cmdAdd, that is again plane jane code behind, and looks like this:

```
   protected void cmdAddOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotels WHERE ID = 0",
                        new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST3)))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            DataTable rst = new DataTable();
            rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            SqlDataAdapter dUpdate = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
            SqlCommandBuilder sUpdate = new SqlCommandBuilder(dUpdate);
            DataRow OneRow = rst.NewRow();

            OneRow["FirstName"] = txtFirst.Text;
            OneRow["LastName"] = txtLast.Text;
            OneRow["HotelName"] = txtHotel.Text;
            OneRow["City"] = txtCity.Text;
            OneRow["Province"] = txtProvince.Text;
            OneRow["Active"] = chkActive.Checked;
            rst.Rows.Add(OneRow);
            dUpdate.Update(rst);

            // now refresh grid to show new row
            LoadGrid();
        }
    }
```

So the final result looks like this:

[image]

And if I ok to add, then we get this:

[image]

However, the above is one of 10,000 ways of doing this, and I choose to use jQuery.UI for this, and as noted, I have no idea which of the 10,000 possible choices and options you are or were using to pop your prompt dialog, since you failed to share that with us.

Now, I am zero upset here - but I MOST certainly am giving you a big push on how to ask better questions here.

The above should give you at least a working design pattern that you can use for popping a dialog, and then prompting the user, adding the row, and THEN VERY important is to re-load the grid to show that row just added.

There are some great ideas in the above - and you can use them for years to come. Good luck!

Edit:

---

Ok, the new example is the pop page is a DIFFERNT page.

So we have a page called AddHotelPop.aspx.

It looks like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <br />
        <div style="text-align:right">
        <p>Hotel Name:<asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>
        <p>First Name:<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>
        <p>Last Name:<asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>
        <p>City:<asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>
        <p>Province:<asp:TextBox ID="txtProvince" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>
        <p>Is Active:<asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox></p>

        <p>
            <asp:Button ID="cmdAddOk" runat="server" Text="Ok-add" OnClick="cmdAddOk_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="cmdCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" Style="margin-left:25px"
                OnClientClick="MyClose();return false"/>
        </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Note how we have the cancel button when clicked will actually call the js code to dismiss the dialog - but the js code to close still remains on the calling page.
Now this works, because the add code in this 2nd page JUMPS BACK to our original page. So the Add button on that 2nd page looks like this:

```
   protected void cmdAddOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotels WHERE ID = 0",
                        new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST3)))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            DataTable rst = new DataTable();
            rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            SqlDataAdapter dUpdate = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
            SqlCommandBuilder sUpdate = new SqlCommandBuilder(dUpdate);
            DataRow OneRow = rst.NewRow();

            OneRow["FirstName"] = txtFirst.Text;
            OneRow["LastName"] = txtLast.Text;
            OneRow["HotelName"] = txtHotel.Text;
            OneRow["City"] = txtCity.Text;
            OneRow["Province"] = txtProvince.Text;
            OneRow["Active"] = chkActive.Checked;
            rst.Rows.Add(OneRow);
            dUpdate.Update(rst);

            Response.Redirect("GridViewFun.aspx");
        }
    }
```

So now our first page? It just loads the grid - code is same as before.

But, now our pop code and markup is this:

```
    <asp:Button ID="cmdAdd" runat="server" Text="Add Hotel" OnClientClick="popadd();return false;"/>

    </div>


    <div id="mypop" style="display:none">
    </div>

        <script>

            function popadd() {
                var mydiv = $('#mypop')
                mydiv.dialog({
                    autoOpen: false, modal: true, title: 'Add Hotel', width: '400px',
                    position: { my: 'top', at: 'top+150' },
                    closeText: ''
                    
                });
                // Open the dialog
                // mydiv.parent().appendTo($("form:first"))
                mydiv.load("AddHotelPop.aspx")
                mydiv.dialog('open')
            }

            function MyClose() {

                var mydiv = $('#mypop')
                mydiv.dialog('close')

            }
        </script>
```

Note NOW how the div pop up is BLANK. We will load + pop the 2nd other page into that div for display.

The results now look the same. The only real differnce is that the add button in the 2nd page does that re-direct back to the first page.

And thus our page will now have the first load - not a post back, and our gird will re-load again.

As noted, we using jQuery.UI for the above, and that .Load() feature is what allows one to pull + load into that div a whole other page.

The UI and screen shots look and work identical as to the above screen shots, but the dialog pop page is now a separate aspx page.

Comment: Sorry for not including the code for popping up the modal. In your code a div is popping up from the same page. I have done this before. It will refresh the gridview correctly. But My problem is with new aspx page (child.aspx) pop up. At the end of ButtonOk click , I'm closing the child window and redirecting to ParentPage. But the gridview is not refreshing. Now I managed it with using a timer to refresh the gridview. But I know that it is not the proper solution.

Comment: Ok, you can have the popup form another page (but then again, as you can see, we needed that detail - it is a huge one!!!). And now we have to deal with a cancel (to dismiss the dialog, or the ok button to save - so dismiss of the page becomes a challenge now. But, jQuery.UI WILL and CAN pop up another page. I'll edit my code when I have some time - and add an example that works like above - but the popup is another page - but that is a whole new and whole different ball of wax - and a somewhat different solution.

Comment: To pop up a different web page? Well then you can't have post-backs unless you pop that page inside of a iframe. And inside a iframe? That that page you pop up can't close the dialog. Talking between different web pages can't be done. If you could do that, then when you come to visit my site, I going to grab your other web pages open - like say the one doing your banking. Now if the other page is JUST markup, then you can probably get that page to work - but if that other page needs post-backs, then you back to an iframe, and you have a real challenge as to how the dialog page is to be closed.

Comment: Ok, as noted, see my edit - it now works by loading a 2nd page, and it does re-fresh just fine if the user hits Add. And if they hit cancel - the dialog is dismissed also jsut fine.